# Perform a two sample t-test on a dataset with a binary independent variable

Tags: r, t-test

I am using the standard function `t.test` to perform a t-test on two variables, one (`FC01`) being an ordinally ranked variable (Likert scale from 1 to 5) and the other (`joko`) one being a nominally scaled binary variable (`TRUE` or `FALSE`).

```r
## Dummy data
ds <- data.frame(FC01 = c(3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2), 
                 joko = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE))
ds$FC01 = factor(ds$FC01, 
                 levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "-9"),
                 labels = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "[NA] Not answered"), 
                 ordered = FALSE)

## t-test
t.test(ds$FC01, ds$joko, var.equal = TRUE)
```

But `t.test` throws this error:

```
> t.test(ds$FC01, ds$joko, var.equal = TRUE)
Error in var(x) : Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
  Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(x) :
  Argument ist weder numerisch noch boolesch: gebe NA zurück
```

#### EDIT

I also ran

```r
all(duplicated(ds$FC01)[-1L])
all(duplicated(ds$joko)[-1L])
```

which resulted in

```
> all(duplicated(ds$FC01)[-1L])
[1] FALSE
> all(duplicated(ds$joko)[-1L])
[1] FALSE
```

but I do not understand what that is supposed to tell me.

Comment: Can you include a sample of your data to make it easier to check your code? For the `t-test` function, you need numeric vectors.

Comment: I cannot replicate the problem with your dummy data. Can you upload dummy data that also produces the error message? Btw. your data specification is invalid. Instead, use this: ds <- data.frame(
  FC01 = c(3,3,4,2,3,1,2,4,3,3,2),
  joko = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
)

Comment: Agree. I opened a new project and tried the code and it somehow worked. This is plain confusing, as i drew the dummy data from my original dataset. I've added a command from the import file, maybe that's why it's not working?

Comment: @nerdyllama The `t.test` function requires a numeric vector, and you're providing a factor...did you try with just numeric values?